# suds soap web service client - multiple dictionary values return issue python

Tags: python, dictionary, soap, suds

So in separate scripts I create a distributed property list database type thing by create dictionary entries in the form:

ID: owner, housenumber, postcode, price

I am then trying to access that property list through a soap web service whereby I can search by either postcode or price range.

It functions almost fine, except the return to the client will only return a maximum of 1 property (even if there are more with the given specification).

soap server code:

```
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Iterable, Integer, Unicode
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
from spyne.decorator import srpc
import Pyro4

class PropertySearch(ServiceBase):

    @srpc(Unicode, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def postcode_search(searchfor):

        warehouse = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:propertylist.warehouse")
        contents = warehouse.list_contents()

        for k in contents:
            if searchfor in contents[k][2]:
                print(k, ":", contents[k])
                return contents[k]
```

with client code:

```
def postcode_option():
    searchfor = input("Please enter a postcode: ")
    print(hello_client.service.postcode_search("{}".format(searchfor)))
```

returns the following output

> SEARCH BY:
>
> 1 - Postcode 2 - Price 3 - Exit
>
> Select an option: 1 Please enter a postcode: CF24 4AN (stringArray){
>   string[] = 
>         "Bob",
>         "23",
>         "CF24 4AN",
>         "150000",  }

But I want to essentially have all of these values in one entry and then all the values of the next property in the next, i.e.

> > string[] = 
> >           "Bob, 23, CF24 4AN, 150000",
> >           "Jim, 24, CF24 4AN, 100000", }

I tried getting rid of the "return contents[k]" line in the server side, which ends up printing the correct output, but ONLY on the server terminal - the client ends up outputting None.

I want to have the client side print the correct output of multiple dictionary entries but am struggling.

I attempted creating a list but there ends up being a getChild error, so I am unsure of how to approach this.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it. For anyone interested, 'Array' had to be imported from spyne and the returns= argument had to be changed to 'Array'